# Exclude derived entities from requests to the base class

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

I have this DbContext:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Base> Bases {get;set}
    public DbSet<Sub> Subs {get;set}
}
```

`Sub` is a subclass of `Base`.

When I'm querying the list of Base entities like so:

```
Context.Bases.ToListAsync()
```

It returns me every entities, either `Base` or `Sub`.

How can I configure my model context to get only the entities that are of `Base` type and not the ones that derives from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to use `OfType<T>`:

```
var basesOnly = await _context.Bases.OfType<Base>().ToListAsync();
```

**UPDATE**

Sorry, then. I could have sworn the above works, but it doesn't. The next best method I can think of is to simply filter out the types you don't want. It's not ideal, because it requires specifying all subtypes in your query, which then means you need to remember to update it if you add more subtypes.

```
var basesOnly = await _context.Bases.Where(x => !(x is Sub)).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: No, as `Sub` _is_ `Base`, when I make this request I get every `Bases` and `Subs` and entities.

Comment: No. `OfType<T>` should return only entities that are specifically the type specified, not just anything that inherits from that type. Did you actually bother to try it before arguing with me?

Comment: Well, I already tried it, so I can confirm it doesn't work (I didn't intend to be agressive :)). `var basesOnly = await _context.Bases.OfType<Base>().Where(b => b.GetType() == typeof(Base)).ToListAsync();` works, but it accualy requests every entities from the DB then procedurally removes `Subs` (wich is not efficient: more data transit and more logic).

Comment: Damn, I was sure I already tried your updated solution. Well, it works but I always have to think about it each time I make a request on `Bases` entities (same as my own answer).

Comment: AFAIK, the `is` operator is translated to SQL, effectively doing the same as your answer with less code bloat. Either way, yes, there's some potential for failure here. You can mitigate that somewhat by adding a separate prop that returns this filtered IQueryable to your context and then use that in your code instead. Then, this at least only exists in one place.

Comment: You're right. It's just sad I can't come up to a cleaner solution using `HasQueryFilter` in `OnModelCreating` for exemple (the main problem is that the exemple `Base` class is actually already a subtype in my code and `HasQueryFilter` has to operate on base types only).

Answer (score 3):

The best (or least worst) solution I found is to directly use the shadow property:

```
Context.Bases.Where(b => EF.Property<string>(b, "Discriminator") == "Base")).ToListAsync();
```

It works but needs to be repeted now and then, each time I need to query `Bases`. I'd have prefered a solution in the `OnModelCreating` method.

I'll accept this answer unless someone else find a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I configure my model context to get only the entities that are
>   of Base type and not the ones that derives from it.

You cannot.  Every Sub *is* a Base.  So querying all Bases includes all Subs.  Eg code like the following must succeed:

```
Base b = db.Bases.Where(i => i.Id == 1).Single();
if (b is Sub)
begin
  Sub s = (Sub)b;
  . . .
end
else //other Sub
begin
  Sub2 s = (Sub2)b;
  . . .

end
```

You can fetch an anonymous type with the just the base class properties.

And asking this question *suggests* that inheritance might is not the right modeling technique for your scenario.

If what you want it to fetch the Entities of type Base, but *not* the subtype Sub, then you can do that with a query like:

```
var q = from b in db.Bases
        where !(b is Sub)
        select b;
```

Which translates to :

```
SELECT [b].[Id], [b].[Discriminator], [b].[Name], [b].[Size]
FROM [Bases] AS [b]
WHERE [b].[Discriminator] IN (N'Sub', N'Base') 
AND NOT ([b].[Discriminator] = N'Sub')
```

But you can't (currently) exclude all subtypes without enumerating them.  Eg this query:

```
var q2 = from b in db.Bases
         where b.GetType() == typeof(Base)
         select b;
```

Will not be completely translated to SQL, and will filter out the subtypes on the client.

Comment: I know that "in code" a Sub _is_ a Base, but when EF Core persist it, it is just a _flat_ table. Then, when EF Core query the table, it uses `WHERE [it].[Discriminator] IN (N'Base', N'Sub')`, so I guess it could be possible to change it for `WHERE [it].[Discriminator] IN (N'Base')` or `WHERE [it].[Discriminator] = N'Base'` in `OnModelCreating`.

Comment: I _have_ to use inheritance, because I still want to be able to cast `Sub` to `Base`, but I don't want to get `Subs` when I request `Bases`.

Comment: If Base is not abstract, you can try using `DbSet<Base>.FromSql` to write a raw SQL query that filters using the Discriminator.

Comment: I'd rather avoid this solution as I always have to remember to exclude the `Subs` in my future requests and I think it could be problematic if ever I need to change the DB provider, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = await _context.classType.OfType<classType>().ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved by creating a separate `DbContext` containing only base class list.

```
public class BaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Base> Bases {get;set}
}
```